# Asp.NET targetFramework Versions and the IIS Application Pool Versions mismatch

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-7.5

Recently I have been creating Application Pool in IIS for Asp.Net Websites. What seems surprising to me is that those App Pools were having v4.0 , while the websites were targeting .Net framework v4.5 / v4.5.1

Entry in Web.config of Individual websites:

and this is what is App Pool Settings:

[image]

Isn't it like for targetFramework="4.5", App Pool version should be 4.5, for targetFRamework="4.5.1", App Pool version should be 4.5.1 ?

Does App Pool version 4.0 handles all Web Application/Websites developed in 4.5 and 4.5.1 as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the 4.0 pool does just as you wished.

Depending on the IIS version you are using, you might see different texts (.NET Framework v4.0.30319 or CLR v4.0.30319) in IIS Manager for application pool settings, but they all mean CLR version. (`managedRuntimeVersion` is the [actual XML setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#configuration)). All .NET Framework 4.x releases use the same CLR version of 4.0.

The actual ASP.NET version of that machine used to host your web apps depends only on the .NET Framework you installed (4.5/4.5.1 following your assumption).

Answer (score 3):

The Application Pool displays the Asp.NET runtime versions, which you can also say as CLR versions.

With the new Asp.NET framework versions various new libraries/functionalities/features are introduced along with (possibly) new Compiler, Build Target files.

As observed from below table, there are NO new CLR versions introduced with framework versions `4.5 -> 4.5.1 ->4.5.2 ...` This means any website developed using framework `v4.5/v4.5.1/v4.5.2` target CLR version `4` and hence use Application Pool version `4.0`

The .NET Framework versions `2.0, 3.0, and 3.5` are built with the same version of the CLR (`CLR 2.0`). These versions represent successive layers of a single installation. Each version is built incrementally on top of the earlier versions.  And therefore you will see Application Pool `v2.0` for these frameworks.

In short,

> **Framework Version != App Pool Version**
>   **App Pool Version = CLR Version**
>   **CLR Version = *Folders at location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework***

[image]

The version folders at location `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\framework` contains the Compiler and Target build files for Asp.NET runtime